# Adjusting the Standard Deviation of a Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, standard-deviation

I have the following company data (in all studies the employees got the same questionnaire). The difference was that the first study was represenatative. we got a random sample (represenative) of companies in our country and they had to participate since it was a government founded study. The non-representative studies (2006 and 2020) are no random samples. Only comanies who wants to pay for it participated.

A 2006 we performed a representative study

B 2006 (we also) performed a study but that was not representative

C 2020 performed a study but that was not representative

The B+C study distributions are left skrewed. So the distribution is steep on the left side and rather flat on the right side.

I want to adjust the Study A by the *changes* between the years 2020 (study B) and 2006 (Study C). So if there was a change in the mean I calculate the difference (Mean Study C - Mean Study B) and add it to the Study A. With the mean this looks trivial but I do not know how to adjust the SD of Study A by the changes between 2020 and 2006 in the SD of Study B and C.

$$ F = \left[(V_A-Mean(V_A))*\frac{SD(V_C)}{SD(V_B)}\right]+Mean(V_A)-[Mean(V_B)-Mean(V_C)]$$

Let us say the differences between the SD of both are 0 then $\frac{SD(V_C)}{SD(V_B)} = 1$ and this would result only in a shift  $$ [V_A-[Mean(V_B)-Mean(V_C)]$$.

I remember that when substracting random variables that VAR[X]+VAR[Y]-2COV[X+Y] and I am not sure whether I can use $\frac{SD(V_C)}{SD(V_B)}$ as I did in the upper formula.

Summary:
I did two non-represenatative studies 2006 and 2020. I want to take the difference in mean and SD and assume that this is the develpment during the time. Now I want to take the representative distribution of 2006 and adjust it so its mean is abjusted by the development between 2020 and 2006.

Comment: Please explain what "$V_A,$" etc. mean.  You use *three* different subscripts in a context concerning only *two* studies, which is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the question and hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Thank you.  Some important details may lurk in what you mean by "not representative."  It appears you are hoping that the *changes* from B to C *are* representative of changes from 2006 to 2020.  Is this the case?  What exactly do you mean by "skewed"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I assume that the changes between 2006 and 2020 can be calculated by substracting both distributions. After this substracting I want to add the changes to the 2006 representative study so I get a 'estimated' 2020 representative study distribution. I edited the question.